# Why after rotating UIImageView size is getting changed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm new in using transformations. And still confusted how they are working.

What I'm trying to do, is to rotate my UIImageView with given angle. But after rotating, it's changing  the size of image, getting smaller. I'm also doing scaling for ImageView so it won't be upside down.**How to rotate and keep the  size, that was given in CGRectMake, when ImageView was allocated ?**

```
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];        

    myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];

    myImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);

    CGAffineTransform newTransform;

    myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,-1);            

    newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(newTransform, 30*M_PI/180);

    [self.window addSubview:myImageView];
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is actually changing? Are you talking about that the frame of the UIImageView changes? Or it is a visible change of the image size? How did you confirm the change? If you rotate a view, it's frame will always change, since the frame represents the view's space inside it's superview. The bounds of the rotated view will stay the same.

Comment: is there any code in touchesBegan:

Comment: @JohannesLumpe It changing weidht of Image, and probably height as well. Yes it is visible change, because Image is getting much smaller, then was before rotating, with that same ImageView given size.

Comment: @RohanKapur No, I just want manually rotate the ImageView and keep correct size.

Comment: @JohannesLumpe I guess, I understood what happening. LIke you said, bounds are staying the same, and only frame is rotating Might I need to set new bounds as well? Is there way to do it?

Comment: @User1234 You don't have to set the bounds, since the bounds always stay the same. Try to NSLog() the frame and the bounds. You will see that after the rotation the frame changes, but the bounds stay the same.

Comment: @JohannesLumpe So it's not possible to rotate, image, with same size, that was before rotating, and with keeping correct ratio?

Comment: @User1234 Sorry I'm outside now. If there won't be a proper answer when I get back home I'll look into it!

Comment: @JohannesLumpe Ok thanks a lot. I will wait for your response.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok I promised I'd look into it, so here's my answer:

I create a scene which should be somewhat equivalent to yours, code as follows:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2-100,
                                                                       self.view.bounds.size.height/2-125,
                                                                       200,
                                                                       250)];

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testimage.jpg"];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

/*
 * I added clipsToBounds, because my test image didn't have a size of 200x250px
 */
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

[self.view addSubview:imageView];

NSLog(@"frame: %@",[NSValue valueWithCGRect:imageView.frame]);
NSLog(@"bounds: %@",[NSValue valueWithCGRect:imageView.bounds]);    

imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(30*M_PI/180);

NSLog(@"frame after rotation: %@",[NSValue valueWithCGRect:imageView.frame]);
NSLog(@"bounds after rotation: %@",[NSValue valueWithCGRect:imageView.bounds]);
```

This code assumes that you are using ARC. If not add

```
[imageView release];
```

at the end.

Using this code the logs look like this:

```
[16221:207] frame: NSRect: {{60, 105}, {200, 250}}
[16221:207] bounds: NSRect: {{0, 0}, {200, 250}}
[16221:207] frame after rotation: NSRect: {{10.897461, 71.746826}, {298.20508, 316.50635}}
[16221:207] bounds after rotation: NSRect: {{0, 0}, {200, 250}}
```

As you can see the bounds always stay the same. What actually changes due to the rotation is the frame, because an image which has been rotated by 30°C is of course wider than if it handn't been rotated. And since the center point has been set to the actual center of the view the origin of the frame also changes (being pushed to the left and the top). Notice that the size of the image itself **does not change**. I didn't use the scale transformation, since the result can be achieved without scaling.

But to make it clearer here are some pictures for you (0°, 30° 90° rotation):
[image: 0°,30° and 90° rotations of UIImageView]

They already look pretty similar, right? I drew the actual frames to make it clear what's the difference between bounds and frame is. The next one really makes it clear. I overlayed all images, rotating them by the negative degrees with which the UIImageView was rotated, giving the following result:
[image: UIImageViews overlayed to show that size doesn't change]

So you see it's pretty straight forward how to rotate images. Now to your problem that you actually want the frame to stay the same. If you want the final frame to have the size of your original frame (in this example with a width of 200 and a height of 250) then you will have to scale the resulting frame. But this will of course result in scaling of the image, which you do not want. I actually think a larger frame will not be a problem for you - you just need to know that you have to take it into account because of the rotation.

In short: it is not possible to have an UIImageView which will have the same frame after rotation. This isn't possible for any UIView. Just think of a rectangle. If you rotate it, it won't be a rectangle after the rotation, will it?

Of course you could put your UIImageView inside another UIView which will have a non-rotated frame with a width of 200 and a height of 250 but that would just be superficial, since it won't really change the fact that a rotated rectangle has a different width and height than the original.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: There's a function `NSStringFromCGRect()` which may be slightly easier than wrapping things in `NSValue`'s like `[NSValue valueWithCGRect:imageView.bounds]`

Comment: There's a whole load of these useful [UIKit functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Awesome answer thanks a lot - tried to do this manually -but complicated with sin and cos so much (was very upset with my low math skills) and then i found this answer and it works perfect !! Huge thanks !!!

Comment: There is also an useful function `NSStringFromCGRect: `. To match your code: `NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect(imageView.frame)];`

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the contentMode which UIImageView inherits from UIView and leads to the changes in frame according to scaling,transformation,device rotation in accordance to the UIViewContentMode you select.

Also if you just want to rotate you can just change the frame using :-

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Rotate" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    CGRect frame=yourView.frame;
    frame.origin.y+=distance you want to rotate;
    yourview.frame=frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

if you dont want the animation just change the frame

Try Using This :-

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
animation.duration = 0.5f;            
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;     // HUGE_VALF is defined in math.h so import it
[self.reloadButton.imageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotation"];
```

Comment: I am using it, so my image won't loose aspect ratio. If I remove it, it won't keep it, and image will look not nice.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but I'm still confused. I just want manually rotate ImageView with given angle.And want to keep aspect ratio, so image will looks correct.More Clear- I want image look the same size, that was before ROTATING,with given bounds. So rotating won't change it's height/weidght.Is it possible?

Comment: what you can do is rotate the image and then scale it to the original

Comment: How can I do it? I'm new in using transformations. Thanks a lot